# Tough integration with change of variables and switch to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I was given this question in class and I was just wondering if I am on the right track…
Evaluate:
$$I=\iint\left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2} -\frac{y^2}{b^2} \right)^{3/2} dxdy $$ over the region enclosed by ellipse $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1 .$$

First I changed $x=au$ and $y=bv$.
Therefore boundary -> $u^2+v^2 \leq1$.

Also I changes $I$ to

$$  I=\iint(1-u^2-v^2)^{3/2}  ab \;dudv $$
From here I switched to polar coordinates and solved the integral.
$$ ab\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^1 r(1-r^2)^{3/2} dr $$

After solving this I ended up with $\frac{2ab}{5}\pi$… Does this look correct? I was just confused about changing variables then applying polar coordinates and was wondering if I made a mistake there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is correct. The problem was done precisely as it should be done.

Comment: Kudos to Andre that was able to understand that mess. @user68203, go to the FAQ section to find directions on how to write LaTeX in this site to properly write mathematics in this site.

Comment: You may answer your own question. In addition to DonAntonio's comment you find some basic information about writing math at this site  [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: I've changed `∅` to $\phi$ (`\phi`) in the last integral. However as you likely know in polar coordinates the standard variable is $\theta$ (`\theta`).

Comment: Thank you guys. And yes sorry for the mess. I will check out those sites for next time.